# Error: method 'First' can only be used as a final query operation

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have the following query:

```
        Dim roommates = From p In dbroom.Residents _
                    Where p.room = queryStudent.First.r.id _
                    Where p.building = queryStudent.First.b.id _
                    Where p.year = year _
                    Where p.semester = term _
                    Select p.person_name
```

It currently returns no results. I was getting an error when attempting to bind this resultset (since it was empty) to a repeater in ASP.NET, so I attempted to escape it:

```
   If roommates.Count() = 0 Then
        Dim nomates As String = "No current roommates."
        rptrRoommates.DataSource = nomates
        rptrRoommates.DataBind()
    Else
        rptrRoommates.DataSource = roommates
        rptrRoommates.DataBind()
    End If
```

But I still get the same error:

> The method 'First' can only be used as a final query operation. Consider using the method 'FirstOrDefault' in this instance instead.

Comment: the error message gives you a suggestion. Have you tried it?

Comment: I'm not sure how I would implement the suggestion in this code instance? I'm trying to get each record in turn, not just the first record.

Comment: In order to implement the suggestion you need to replace `First` by `FirstOrDefault`. What exactly is your `queryStudent`? It could help if you post the code relevant to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use subquery this way. Either execute subqueries separately and use only received ids in the main query or rewrite the query to use joins.

Comment: What do you mean by subqueries? Where I reference queryStudent? Or the fact that I have multiple Where clauses?

Answer (score 6):

In a LINQ to Entities query, you can use either FirstOrDefault() or SingleOrDefault as the final query operation.

```
var right = Context.Foos
                       .Where(f => f.SomeBoolean)
                       .FirstOrDefault();        // works
    var works = Context.Foos
                       .Where(f => f.SomeBoolean)
                       .SingleOrDefault();       // works
```

However, inside the query, you cannot use SingleOrDefault:

```
var wrong = Context.Foos
                   .Where(f => f.SomeBoolean)
                   .Select(f => f.Bars.SingleOrDefault())
                   .SingleOrDefault();            // Runtime error
var right = Context.Foos
                   .Where(f => f.SomeBoolean)
                   .Select(f => f.Bars.FirstOrDefault())
                   .SingleOrDefault();            // works
```

Note that the final SingleOrDefault is always OK, but we had to change the one inside the query to FirstOrDefault. The reason for this is how SingleOrDefault is implemented. It tells the DB server to return the first two records and then throws an exception if more than one is returned. The LINQ to Entities query -- everything up until the final SingleOrDefault -- will be converted to SQL. That error behavior is not straightforward to express in a pure SQL query.

Ref : [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/3908.entity-framework-faq-error-messages.aspx#The_methods_Single_and_SingleOrDefault_can_only_be_used_as_a_final_query_operation_Consider_using_the_method_FirstOrDefault_in_this_instance_instead)